# ActiveMQ Artemis Queue does not distribute messages evenly to the STOMP-Consumers. How can we achieve an even load-balancing?

Tags: spring-boot, stomp, activemq-artemis

[image: STOMP consumer architecture diagram]

As demonstrated in the diagram, out of **n** messages published on the queue - `/queue/msgs`, the distribution among the consumers (`STOMP-Consumer 1` and `STOMP-Consumer 2`) is uneven. I could observe, `STOMP-Consumer 2` only received one message out of **n** messages.

Exact same STOMP headers are passed by both the consumers. Those are as follows -

**STOMP CONNECT Headers**

- client-id: app

**STOMP SUBSCRIBE Headers**

- durable-subscription-name: app-subscription
- auto-delete: false
- ack: client-individual
- destination: /queue/msgs

**Broker.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <configuration
        xmlns="urn:activemq"
        xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:activemq /schema/artemis-configuration.xsd">
        <core
            xmlns="urn:activemq:core" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:activemq:core ">
            <name>activemq-558f6696fc-2kx8q</name>
            <persistence-enabled>true</persistence-enabled>
            <journal-type>ASYNCIO</journal-type>
            <paging-directory>data/paging</paging-directory>
            <bindings-directory>data/bindings</bindings-directory>
            <journal-directory>data/journal</journal-directory>
            <large-messages-directory>data/large-messages</large-messages-directory>
            <journal-datasync>true</journal-datasync>
            <journal-min-files>2</journal-min-files>
            <journal-pool-files>10</journal-pool-files>
            <journal-device-block-size>4096</journal-device-block-size>
            <journal-file-size>10M</journal-file-size>
            <journal-buffer-timeout>24000</journal-buffer-timeout>
            <journal-max-io>4096</journal-max-io>
            <disk-scan-period>5000</disk-scan-period>
            <max-disk-usage>90</max-disk-usage>
            <critical-analyzer>true</critical-analyzer>
            <critical-analyzer-timeout>120000</critical-analyzer-timeout>
            <critical-analyzer-check-period>60000</critical-analyzer-check-period>
            <critical-analyzer-policy>HALT</critical-analyzer-policy>
            <page-sync-timeout>368000</page-sync-timeout>
            <acceptors>
                <acceptor name="artemis">tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;amqpMinLargeMessageSize=102400;protocols=CORE,AMQP,STOMP,HORNETQ,MQTT,OPENWIRE;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpLowCredits=300;amqpDuplicateDetection=true</acceptor>
                <acceptor name="amqp">tcp://0.0.0.0:5672?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=AMQP;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpLowCredits=300;amqpMinLargeMessageSize=102400;amqpDuplicateDetection=true</acceptor>
                <acceptor name="stomp">tcp://0.0.0.0:61613?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=STOMP;useEpoll=true</acceptor>
                <acceptor name="hornetq">tcp://0.0.0.0:5445?anycastPrefix=jms.queue.;multicastPrefix=jms.topic.;protocols=HORNETQ,STOMP;useEpoll=true</acceptor>
                <acceptor name="mqtt">tcp://0.0.0.0:1883?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=MQTT;useEpoll=true</acceptor>
            </acceptors>
            <security-settings>
                <security-setting match="#">
                    <permission type="createNonDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
                    <permission type="deleteNonDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
                    <permission type="createDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
                    <permission type="deleteDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
                    <permission type="createAddress" roles="amq"/>
                    <permission type="deleteAddress" roles="amq"/>
                    <permission type="consume" roles="amq"/>
                    <permission type="browse" roles="amq"/>
                    <permission type="send" roles="amq"/>
                    <!-- we need this otherwise ./artemis data imp wouldn't work -->
                    <permission type="manage" roles="amq"/>
                </security-setting>
            </security-settings>
            <message-expiry-scan-period>30000</message-expiry-scan-period>
            <connection-ttl-override>60000</connection-ttl-override>
            <address-settings>
                <address-setting match="activemq.management#">
                    <dead-letter-address>DLQ</dead-letter-address>
                    <expiry-address>ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
                    <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>
                    <!-- with -1 only the global-max-size is in use for limiting -->
                    <max-size-bytes>-1</max-size-bytes>
                    <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
                    <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
                    <auto-create-queues>true</auto-create-queues>
                    <auto-create-addresses>true</auto-create-addresses>
                    <auto-create-jms-queues>true</auto-create-jms-queues>
                    <auto-create-jms-topics>true</auto-create-jms-topics>
                </address-setting>
                <address-setting match="/queue/#">
                    <default-address-routing-type>ANYCAST</default-address-routing-type>
                    <default-queue-routing-type>ANYCAST</default-queue-routing-type>
                </address-setting>
                <address-setting match="/topic/#">
                    <default-address-routing-type>MULTICAST</default-address-routing-type>
                    <default-queue-routing-type>MULTICAST</default-queue-routing-type>
                </address-setting>
                <address-setting match="#">
                    <dead-letter-address>DLQ</dead-letter-address>
                    <expiry-address>ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
                    <auto-delete-queues>false</auto-delete-queues>
                    <auto-delete-jms-queues>false</auto-delete-jms-queues>
                    <auto-delete-jms-topics>false</auto-delete-jms-topics>
                    <auto-delete-addresses>false</auto-delete-addresses>
                    <max-size-bytes>-1</max-size-bytes>
                    <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
                    <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
                    <auto-create-queues>true</auto-create-queues>
                    <auto-create-addresses>true</auto-create-addresses>
                    <auto-create-jms-queues>true</auto-create-jms-queues>
                    <auto-create-jms-topics>true</auto-create-jms-topics>
                    <redelivery-delay-multiplier>1</redelivery-delay-multiplier>
                    <redelivery-collision-avoidance-factor>0.15</redelivery-collision-avoidance-factor>
                    <max-redelivery-delay>50000</max-redelivery-delay>
                    <default-consumer-window-size>0</default-consumer-window-size>
                </address-setting>
            </address-settings>
            <addresses>
                <address name="DLQ">
                    <anycast>
                        <queue name="DLQ"/>
                    </anycast>
                </address>
                <address name="ExpiryQueue">
                    <anycast>
                        <queue name="ExpiryQueue"/>
                    </anycast>
                </address>
            </addresses>
            <wildcard-addresses>
                <routing-enabled>true</routing-enabled>
                <delimiter>/</delimiter>
                <any-words>#</any-words>
                <single-word>*</single-word>
            </wildcard-addresses>
        </core>
    </configuration>
```

**The acceptor in use is the artemis acceptor with port 61616**

Comment: @JustinBertram Kindly excuse me, it was a late-night post :). I wanted to write ANYCAST there.

Comment: @JustinBertram I have added the complete broker.xml

Comment: @JustinBertram I have added the requested details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `acceptor` URL parameter `stompConsumerCredits`. The default value for this is `10240` bytes which means that the broker will dispatch 10KB worth of messages to each client. If the first client processes these messages quickly enough then other consumers can starve. Assuming that your STOMP consumers are using `stomp` `acceptor` then you could try something like this:

```xml
<acceptor name="stomp">tcp://0.0.0.0:61613?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=STOMP;useEpoll=true;stompConsumerCredits=1</acceptor>
```

Keep in mind that dispatching messages to consumers in batches based on `stompConsumerCredits` is a performance optimization which prevents lots of network round-trips between the client and the broker to fetch messages. I recommend you test different values for `stompConsumerCredits` to find the optimum performance for your use-case as using a small value for 2 consumers may actually *reduce* overall message throughput vs. a large value for 1 consumer.

Also, it's worth noting that in ActiveMQ Artemis 2.16.0 (not yet released) you'll be able to use a custom header (i.e. `consumer-window-size`) on the STOMP `SUBSCRIBE` frame to tune this per client instead of having it set at the `acceptor` level for all consumers.

Comment: I can see consumer-window-size related docs - https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/blob/master/docs/user-manual/en/stomp.md
Any idea on the 2.16 release date or any plan?

Comment: Also, stompConsumerCredits, say if it is 10KB, does that mean I can not send messages bigger than 10KB to a consumer? Does it limit the message size for one consumer?

Comment: Of course you can see it in the GitHub repository. However, those changes were added *after* the release of 2.15.0. They will be in 2.16.0 as I indicated previously. If you want those changes now you're certainly free to build it yourself based on the master branch.

Comment: You can send messages larger than `stompConsumerCredits` to the client.

Comment: To be clear, there's currently no release date for 2.16.0.